# Thymeleaf Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set up Thymeleaf in my Spring MVC application but somethings goes wrong

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and here is my configuration

```
package thyme.leaf.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("my.package")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        return viewResolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

the problem is somewhere with TemplateResolver class in my methods. Unfortunatelly it can not be found at all. I inspected org.thymeleaf.templateresolver package where I think it should be but it is not there

can anybody advice what is wrong here please

Comment: *'but something goes wrong'*... Maybe explain what goes wrong... Add a stacktrace... Be more specific instead of dumping code here and expect us to exactly expect to know what goes wrong. One thing why do you have the spring3 and spring4 dependencies... Use 1 not both (one is for Spring 3 the other Spring 4).

Comment: TemplateResolver class not found neither in spring3 nor spring4

Comment: You don't have a thymeleaf dependency... Only the spring integration library, add thymeleaf.

Comment: added org.thymeleaf -> thymeleaf -> 3.0.1.RELEASE and it doesn't help

Comment: The recommended one is to use `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` with Spring. Next to that the way you use `ServletContextTemplateResolver` is old and wouldn't even construct (as the new one requires a `ServletContext` as constructor argument). So not sure what you are adding dependency wise it isn't going to work either way... (I suggest reading some of the thymeleaf documentation belonging to the version you are using).

Comment: can you please post the updated pom? also, from the previous comments, if you are using spring 4 you should use thymeleaf for spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found correct implementation:

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
            resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
            resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            return resolver;
        }

        @Bean
        public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
            SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
            engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
            engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
            return engine;
        }

        private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
            SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
            resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
            resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
            return resolver;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` should be a bean... It implements some callback interfaces for spring (and you can remove the `ApplicationContextAware` from the confiugration class as that will be called then (`SpringResourceTemplateResolver` implements the same interface).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try to change `@ComponentScan("my.package")` with `@ComponentScan("thyme.leaf.config")`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this doesn't help. error occures before component scan. TemplateResolver class not found

Comment: Can you give us the stack trace ?